# Heatmap - Generating Simple 'HeatPoint' Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, heatmap

Android SDK 2.3.3
Google Maps V2

Currently I'm drawing circles overlays and adding them to a MapView. The size is dictated by a certain value and I'm looking to determine the RadialGradient color of the circle by something else.

```
            circle.setShader(new RadialGradient(pt.x, pt.y, 40, Color.argb(150, 252, 5, 5), Color.argb(60, 234, 231, 0), TileMode.MIRROR));
            canvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, radius, circle);
```

It works, however I'd prefer the edges to look more similar to the classic heatpoint map.

Current

[image: current heat map]

What I'd like to achieve (I'd still like the shape to be circular)

[image: desired heat map]

I'm thinking of possibly drawing a circle directly underneath the current with a sightly bigger area in order to achieve a more typical heatmap look, however this has performance implications considering I'm doing this on a mobile device which has to re-render per zoom in or out action.

Comment: What level of data do you have? Are you just trying to improve the look of the marker that indicates individual points, or do you have information about frequency of multiple points?

Comment: Nah I don't have multiple points, this is purely from a looks perspective. Adding an additional overlay behind the circle would be good enough to achieve a better 'look' I just want to avoid the overhead. I guess reading up on the Drawing class library is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Erm what? I can't do anything like this on my Google Maps v2 for Android - Circle does not have the method setShader - Can you explain what your doing please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few obvious options here, and I'm sure there are many more non-obvious ways to do this as well:

- Draw multiple concentric circles as you suggested
- Load a concentric circle pattern from an image and draw that (less rendering, but, of course, you have to load the image)
- Use a `BitmapShader` to draw a single circle with a custom gradient that matches what you're looking for: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html

Unfortunately, I don't know which of these options will give you the best performance, so you'll probably have to test them yourself. I suspect that, for a large number of heatmap points, one of the later two options will be more efficient, but that's nothing more than a guess.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have an explore :)