# Android - Google Maps v2 - Gradient Circle

Tags: android, gradient, google-maps-android-api-2, geometry

[Heatmap - Generating Simple 'HeatPoint' Google Maps Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762936/heatmap-generating-simple-heatpoint-google-maps-android)

SO the above seems to suggest i can do this, however I am not convinced.

Here is what I am doing

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
                            .center(center)
                            .radius(distance.distanceInMeters)
                            .strokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brand_color_very_faded))
                            .strokeWidth(8F)
                            .fillColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.brand_color_faded)); // In meters

                        // Get back the mutable Circle
                        Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

Which works fine, however I would really like to use a smooth gradient color, is this possible?

Or am i going to have to add a marker at each point, with a bitmap gradient (not what I want to do)?

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you are referring to talks about drawing on `Bitmap` using `Canvas`, not about using `CircleOptions`. I suggest following it and also using `TileOverlay` or `GroundOverlay` depending on how many of these circles you may have.

Comment: I have tried this wya using GroundOverlay however I am coming into isues with transparency, if you have a second could you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198447/android-bitmapdescriptor-from-xml-shape-transparent-is-black